# Destroying clone of prefab with a button which is spawned by a different button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity Project in which 3D objects like Cube, Sphere & Cylinder spawn at the center of the screen when selected from a dropdown button list. The instantiate script is working fine but all 3 objects spawn and merge with each other. It is expected to destroy the other 2 when one of them is instantiated. The issue I'm facing is the object spawned is a clone and I can't get it to be destroyed. I'm a beginner to Unity and trying to learn. I've pasted the code below, I've created 3 of these for each button and changed the parameters as per the object.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Cube_Inst : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject box;
    public Transform pos;
    public bool trigger;
    public Button yourButton;
    public GameObject Sphere_Destroy;
    public GameObject Cylinder_Destroy;



    void Start()
    {
        Button btn = yourButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }
    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        trigger = true;
        Destroy(Sphere_Destroy);
        Destroy(Cylinder_Destroy);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (trigger == true)
        {
            Instantiate(box, pos.position, pos.rotation);
            trigger = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rather implement the entire thing centralized ("Single responsibility pattern").

Don't let the individual buttons have individual scripts with a ton of cross references between them.

Rather have one central controller component and let the buttons pass in different parameters to a general spawn method.

Also you should do it event driven - you already know the moment a button is clicked - instead of poll checking a flag in the `Update` method.
I would use something like

```
// Put this on ONE object that is always active in the Scene
public class SpawnController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject _currentClone;
    private GameObject _currentPrefab;

    public void SetInstance(GameObject prefab, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)
    {
        // Was the same prefab passed again? -> Ignore
        if(prefab == _currentPrefab) return;

        _currentPrefab = prefab;

        // Already exists a clone? -> Destroy it
        if(_currentClone) Destroy(_currentClone);

        // Create and store the new clone
        _currentClone = Instantiate (prefab, position, rotation);
    }
}
```

So if `SetInstance` is called it automatically destroys any already existing instance.

And then have the same component on each button but only configure them accordingly

```
public class SpawnButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Already reference this via the Inspector if possible
    // If not we will get it on runtime as fallback
    [SerializeField] private Button _button; 

    // For each different button reference a different prefab
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _prefab;  
    // Reference the spawn point
    [SerializeField] private Transform _spawnPoint;

    // Here drag in the SpawnController from the scene if possible
    // if not, we will find it on runtime as fallback
    [SerializeField] private SpawnController _spawnController;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_button) _button = Get component<Button>();

        _button.onClick.AddListener(DoSpawn());

        if(!_spawnController) _spawnController = FindObjectOfType<SpawnController>();
    }

    private void DoSpawn()
    {
        // Only tell the SpawnController to do its thing
        // This button doesn't have to know or care what that means for the Scene

        _spawnController.SetInstance(_prefab, _spawnPoint.position, _spawnPoint.rotation);
    }
}
```

---

You could even take a step beyond and don't let the buttons know the `SpawnController` and its secret `SetInstance` method at all and rather do something like

```
public class SpawnController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject _currentClone;
    private Button _lastClickedButton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        SpawnButton.OnSpawnButtonClicked += SetInstance;
    }

    private void SetInstance(Button button, GameObject prefab, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)
    {
        // Was the same button pressed again? -> Ignore
        if(button == _lastClickedButton) return;

        _lastClickedButton = button;

        // Already exists a clone? -> Destroy it
        if(_currentClone) Destroy(_currentClone);

        // Create and store the new clone
        _currentClone = Instantiate (prefab, position, rotation);
    }
}
```

and then

```
public class SpawnButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Action<Button, GameObject, Vector3, Quaternion> OnSpawnButtonClicked;

    // Already reference this via the Inspector if possible
    // If not we will get it on runtime as fallback
    [SerializeField] private Button _button; 

    // For each different button reference a different prefab
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _prefab;  
    // Reference the spawn point
    [SerializeField] private Transform _spawnPoint;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_button) _button = Get component<Button>();

        _button.onClick.AddListener(DoSpawn());
    }

    private void DoSpawn()
    {
        // Only Invoke the event
        // You don't care if or who is listening
        OnSpawnButtonClicked?.Invoke(this, _prefab, _spawnPoint.position, _spawnPoint.rotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Really appreciated